# Any way to stream YouTube sound off of Nexus 7 to Yamaha amp over Airplay?

Tags: youtube, airplay

I have the following 3 devices:

1. a Nexus 7
2. an iPhone 4s
3. a [Yamaha RX-473](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/audio-visual/av-receivers-amps/rx/rx-v473_black_u/), which supports airplay

All are hooked up over my wifi. I've setup Airplay with the amp and the iPhone, allowing me to watch videos on my iPhone and hear the sound out of the Yamaha amplifier, but I'd love to use the Nexus 7's larger screen to watch youtube videos.

Is there any way to wirelessly stream youtube audio from my Nexus 7 to my Yamaha receiver, in the same way that I can using my iPhone?

I purchased the [AirSync](http://doubletwist.com/airsync/) application, but it appears as though that only works for music and video I have on my Nexus 7, not streamed youtube apps, so its not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and exploit your receiver's support for the DLNA / UPnP protocols, by installing a DLNA / UPnP control point app, such as [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp).

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on Gizmodo that has a number of ways to do this, some are paid and some are free. https://gizmodo.com/how-to-stream-anything-from-android-to-airplay-1578516449 is the link. Some of the apps it recommends are DoubleTwist, Allcast, Allstream, AppleTV Airplay Media Player, and Twonky Beam. Some of these(not all of these) require a root.

Answer (score 0):

Most including yamaha would not accept mp4 format. These apps send as mp4 for youtube. Not sure how airplay send it. May be convert to mp3 and send?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Nobody else has mentioned "mp4 format" but you. The question is about using the Yamaha amp as an output, not about sending files.